# Configuring Visual Studio Debugger to Not Break on Exceptions?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, try-catch

The Visual Studio's debugger can break execution of your application immediately when an exception occurs. 
For example (a trivial one):

```
try{
    a= b/0; // Faulty code
}
catch(.){
    printf("I know the code above is faulty.");
}
```

When you execute the program, Visual Studio always break at the faulty code. How can I configure it to not break if there's an exception arised from a C++ `try{} catch {} block`?

Comment: What do you mean by "an exception spawn from a `try{} catch{} block`"? I can't figure out what you're trying to use the word "spawn" to mean in this context.

Comment: (It is often beneficial to include a [fuller] sample in questions.)

Comment: Include the language in the tags as well :) Is it managed or unmanaged C++?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The following applies to C#/CLR. I do not know if there is an equivalent for [unmanaged] C++ code.

---

You can't -- the options are "break on thrown" or "break on unhandled".

However, what *can* be done, is the *entire method* can be annotated with the [DebuggerNonUserCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx) attribute. With this annotation, the debugger will not break for exceptions generated -- and handled -- from within the method. (It will still break for exceptions propagated *out* of the method.)

> The common language runtime attaches no semantics to this attribute. It is provided for use by source code debuggers. For example, *in Visual Studio 2005 [and 2010], the debugger does not display an element with this attribute in the debugger window, does not stop in a method with this attribute [including when exceptions are thrown from a called method], and does not allow a breakpoint to be set in the method*.

Use with caution :)

Alternatively, it may be beneficial to simply *exclude* some class of exceptions from being trapped by the debugger, if it applies, as it is a less intrusive approach.

Happy coding.